# When I modulate a JSP file, Can I include its javascript functions like this?

Tags: javascript, jsp

If there's a JSP file like this,

```
...
<div id="header" onclick="hideHeader()">
...
</div>
<div id="body">
...
</div>
<div id="footer">
...
</div>
<script>
 function hideHeader() { ... }
...
</script>
...
```

I want to modulate "#header" part into another JSP file. 
But there's a Javascript function connected to a click event on "#header".

In this situation, is it okay to make & include a new JSP file looks like underneath? 
I think it's not looking good, because in this way, there could be several 'script' tags between html codes.

So I want to hear what you're thinking about this. 
If there's a better way, please let me know. 
Thank you.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<div id="header" onclick="hideHeader()">
...
</div>
<script>
  function hideHeader() {...}
</script>
```

```
...
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
<div id="body">
...
</div>
<div id="footer">
...
</div>
<script>
...
</script>
...
```

Comment: One way would be to store all script related to one element i.e : header,footer etc together in one file so that you can add the directly in your current page

Comment: @Swati Thank you! It looks much better that way.